# Why does percent ionization of a weak acid decrease when the initial weak acid concentration increases?

Tags: acid-base

By the rules of the equibrilium, as the concentration of the acid increases, the reaction will want to dissolve more. So why does the percent ionization of a weak acid or base decrease when the initial weak acid concentration increases?

Comment: If you wrote the equilibrium equation and enumerated it for 2 different nonionized acid concentrations, you would know the answer faster than by posting the question and waiting for answer.

Comment: Ostwald Dilution Law might help..